# Is use of many static members problematic?

Tags: c++, static

In my C++ application I have several classes which consists only of some static members.

Most of them are double values or other fundamental types, but some are some (reasonable) big lookup tables (like `static unordered_map< string, vector< vector< myClassType > > >`...)

The variables are mostly parameters and lookup tables that I need in a lot of different places in the code. I did not want to always have to hand over all of these parameters and tables so I decided to put them in different classes and simply import the class and then use the variables.

Is there any problem with this approach, concerning speed or safety? I do not really see anything during profiling but I would like to know if this is "good practice" or if one should handle this problem differently (I did not want to use global variables so I used this approach).

Comment: Seems to me you are using a class type to implement namespaces

Comment: It looks OK to me. There shouldn't be any performance hits not safety problems.

Comment: Well, using class to implement namespace has huge advantage - it allows to specify access level to static fields declared in those classes may not be treated as global variables.

Comment: *"(I did not want to use global variables so I used this approach)"* public static members are very similar to regular global...

Comment: Calling your global "SomeClass::foo" instead of "foo" doesn't make it any less problematic. The problem with globals is not the scope of the name but its being globally shared mutable state.

Comment: I would probably advice against this - Instead of showing what dependencies a class has you are hiding it by using static access. One day you will move the initialization of your data and one class that depends on it will be clueless as to why it didn't find the data that it expects. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between using globals or static members you don't have perfomance changes.

Regarding safety, with static members you are sure to have only one instance, as exmplained here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration (look for static part)

> If multiple threads attempt to initialize the same static local variable concurrently, the initialization occurs exactly once (similar behavior can be obtained for arbitrary functions with std::call_once).
>   Note: usual implementations of this feature use variants of the double-checked locking pattern, which reduces runtime overhead for already-initialized local statics to a single non-atomic boolean comparison.